# Get list of contacts matching a give set of phone numbers

Tags: android, android-contacts

I am trying to get the list of contacts matching a given set of phone numbers, can anyone suggest me how to do this in android.

e.g.Say I have 3 phone numbers [883338383 , 93939311 , 89898999] which are the inputs used to search. I need to get the list of contacts which match these numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a URI and a query to get contact info with a phone number.

```
Uri contactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(Contacts.Phones.CONTENT_FILTER_URL, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));

Cursor cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(contactUri, null, null, null, null);
```

The cursor returned by the code above should then contain the contact you are looking for you can parse it to get the info you need:

```
if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
    int personIDIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(Contacts.Phones.PERSON_ID);
    //etc
}
```

If there is no contact with the given number, then the query will return null. So make sure t0 check the cursor for null value before you pares or you'll get a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: But I guess will have to do this one by one number right? In one shot is there a way to pass all the 3 numbers and get the list of contacts?

Comment: No, there isn't. Use a for loop. Don't worry about efficiency since this operation is usually pretty quick and you only have 3 numbers.

Comment: I just took 3 numbers as an example , this number may vary , anyways thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Even then, unless you have many thousands of numbers in each query, I wouldn't worry about the efficiency.

Comment: but even if we have 1000 numbers is there any other way which can avoid this looping queries?

Comment: Maybe different ways to package the query but the end result will be the same.